# How to create a keypad lock to an app?

Tags: android

I'm searching for a program. That is nothing but keypad lock programme.

I have a program for that I have to set a keypad lock as security could you please help me in that. How to programme keypad lock?

Answer (score 1):

If what you are wanting to do is to hide the soft keypad (the touch keyboard that inflates on the screen for you to use) there are a few options to try

`Option 1:` You can hide the soft keyboard, if that is what you are talking about. First you need to get a view that is inside of your current window, or create one

```
View v = findViewById(R.id.view_id);
//or something like EditText mEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.view_id);
```

or if you don't have a view in your window, create a new view

```
View v = new View(this);
```

Then using that view, you can initialize an InputMethodManager, get the window token via your view, and then call on your InputMethodManager to force your keyboard into hiding

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(
        Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

OR

`Option 2:` Set the keyboard as hidden via your window manager

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.
        LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

OR

`Option 3:` Declare the keyboard hidden in your manifest for your activity/application

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"
```

One of those 3 ways should work if what you are trying to do is hide your soft key pad